# How to specify the min/max length of an array field in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array inside the `$_POST` variable and i want to validate it:

```
$this->validator->set_rules('questions[]', 'questions', 'required|min_length[10]');
```

In this case i want the array `questions` to have length at least 10, the problem is that this doesn't work, for arrays with length < 10 the validator detects no error, here is my dumped post example:

`array(1) { ["questions"]=> array(0) {} }`

when i run:

`if($this->validator->run() == false){...}else{...}`

the method return true and the code will enter in the `else`.

Do someone knows how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a callback function, I am giving an example.
Suppose you want to limit your array for minimum 10 values.

```
$this->validator->set_rules('questions[]', 'questions', required|callback_checkLength');
```

And write the function like this :

```
function checkLength(){
   if(count($this->input->post("questions[]") < 10) { return false };
   else { return true; }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: with this approach i have to declare my variable `$POST`(the one being validated) as global since the function is called for each element in the array `questions`, even if i use the field `questions` instead of `questions[]` because in the first case CI wont pass anything as a parameter to the callback. I can go with it, but i would like to know if there is other options...